# Singular perturbation theory in non-standard form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, stability-in-odes, perturbation-theory

Singular perturbation theory in ODE's is a well treated and highly studied subject. Most of the references I can find take the form,

\begin{align}
   \dot{x} &=f\left( x,z,\varepsilon  \right) \\ 
  \varepsilon \dot{z}&=g\left( x,z,\varepsilon  \right) \\ 
\end{align}

where there is an explicit separation of the state variables into slow mode $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and fast mode $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I was wondering if anyone can point me to a complete treatment of the more general case:

1. $$ \varepsilon \dot{x}=f\left( x,\varepsilon  \right) $$
   where there is no explicit separation or
2. $$ \varepsilon \dot{x}=f\left( x,\varepsilon  \right)+g\left(x \right) $$

I believe in the second case a reduction to the standard form can be made by some coordinate change; but how would one go about constructing such a coordinate change? Can such a coordinate change be found in the first case?

A treatment of the linear case:

$$ \varepsilon \dot{x}=\left( A+\varepsilon B\left( \varepsilon  \right) \right)x $$

can be found [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1026104) but I can't seem to find any material on the most general non-linear case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general treatment does not exist at this moment; however, I would advise to keep a close eye on [this upcoming title](https://www.springer.com/series/13763). In the mean time, geometric singular perturbation theory analysis of specific systems in non-standard form can be found [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.3577998), [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00332-015-9235-z), [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00285-015-0905-0) or [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/100791233), to name just a few.

Comment: Thats unfortunate. I did find [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1085372) which considers a special form of the second case in the question.

Comment: You'll just have to be patient, I guess. Feel free to accept the answer, btw!